# How to replace 1 string with either of 2 strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

Say I've this

`string = SSTTFSSFFST`

Now I want to replace every F's with either X or Y so the result is like using python 3x:

```
new_string =  SSTTXSSXXST, SSTTXSSXYST, SSTTXSSYXST, SSTTXSSYYST, SSTTYSSXXST, SSTTYSSXYST, SSTTYSSYXST, SSTTYSSYYST
```

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: what criteria determines whether to use an X or Y for the replacement?

Comment: @gregory The OP simply wants all variations. See the resulting new strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution, albeit it not the most efficient:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

string = "SSTTFSSFFST"
n = string.count('F')
replacements = 'XY' * n
strings = []
for chars in set(combinations(replacements, n)):
    s = string
    for char in chars:
        s = s.replace('F', char, 1)
    strings.append(s)
print(sorted(strings))
```

This results in:

```
['SSTTXSSXXST', 'SSTTXSSXYST', 'SSTTXSSYXST', 'SSTTXSSYYST', 
 'SSTTYSSXXST', 'SSTTYSSXYST', 'SSTTYSSYXST', 'SSTTYSSYYST']
```